# Android System Services not available error

Tags: android, android-wake-lock

I want to try to use system service such as wakelock but for some reason when i run it errors saying **"System Services not available to Activities before onCreate()"** I tried changing a little of the wakelock to see if it would fix it by moving the newWakeLock into the `oncreate()` but that still does not work, what can fix this?

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    String[] activities = {"package1", "package2", "package3"};

    private PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    //@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock; //= powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
        wakeLock.acquire();
        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter (this,    android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, activities));
    }   

    public void onPause(){
        wakeLock.release();
    }

    public void onResume(){ }

    public void onDestroy(){ }

    /*  public void onListItemClick(ListView, View, int, long){    }*/    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line :

```
 powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
```

should be placed in your `onCreate` method.

Before that, activity is not alive and doesn't have a access to Android services.